# Why is WinCertStore not showing Personal Certificates?

Tags: python, oauth, certificate, azure-ad-msal

We have a personal certificate in (Local Computer)\Personal\Certificates.  I am trying to load this certificate to obtain the private key to use with the msal python package for Azure AD authentication.

I am attempting to do this with the python package wincertstore, but the certificate doesnt seem to be found.

```
if os.name == 'nt':
  for storename in ("ROOT", "CA", "MY"):
    with wincertstore.CertSystemStore(storename) as store:
      for cert in store.itercerts(usage=None):
        print(f'{storename} - {cert.get_name()}')
```